# What ways exist to create an array with given dimensions from a given sequence in Julia?

Tags: julia

I'm new to Julia and I could not find any useful information on the following: I would like to create an array of given dimensions and fill it with a given sequence.

```
m,n = 10,10 # dimensions
i = 1:100 # sequence
```

I've tried to use `collect`, but this gives me a single column array. I have also tried it the Julia way

```
[? for i in 1:m, j in 1:n]
```

but I don't know what I could insert for `?`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is `reshape(i, m,n)` (potentially together with a `collect` if you really need an `Array{Int64,2}`):

```
julia> reshape(i,m,n)
10×10 reshape(::UnitRange{Int64}, 10, 10) with eltype Int64:
  1  11  21  31  41  51  61  71  81   91
  2  12  22  32  42  52  62  72  82   92
  3  13  23  33  43  53  63  73  83   93
  4  14  24  34  44  54  64  74  84   94
  5  15  25  35  45  55  65  75  85   95
  6  16  26  36  46  56  66  76  86   96
  7  17  27  37  47  57  67  77  87   97
  8  18  28  38  48  58  68  78  88   98
  9  19  29  39  49  59  69  79  89   99
 10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100

julia> collect(ans)
10×10 Array{Int64,2}:
  1  11  21  31  41  51  61  71  81   91
  2  12  22  32  42  52  62  72  82   92
  3  13  23  33  43  53  63  73  83   93
  4  14  24  34  44  54  64  74  84   94
  5  15  25  35  45  55  65  75  85   95
  6  16  26  36  46  56  66  76  86   96
  7  17  27  37  47  57  67  77  87   97
  8  18  28  38  48  58  68  78  88   98
  9  19  29  39  49  59  69  79  89   99
 10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100
```

To answer your question what to put as `?` in the array comprehension approach, you must convert the cartesian index to a linear index, for example like so:

```
julia> [i[LinearIndices((m,n))[p,q]] for p in 1:m, q in 1:n]
10×10 Array{Int64,2}:
  1  11  21  31  41  51  61  71  81   91
  2  12  22  32  42  52  62  72  82   92
  3  13  23  33  43  53  63  73  83   93
  4  14  24  34  44  54  64  74  84   94
  5  15  25  35  45  55  65  75  85   95
  6  16  26  36  46  56  66  76  86   96
  7  17  27  37  47  57  67  77  87   97
  8  18  28  38  48  58  68  78  88   98
  9  19  29  39  49  59  69  79  89   99
 10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100
```

Of course, you can also calculate the linear index yourself, `[i[(q-1)*m + p] for p in 1:m, q in 1:n]`.

Alternatively, you can preallocate the array and fill it in a linear fashion:

```
julia> result = Matrix{Int64}(undef, m,n);

julia> result[:] .= i;

julia> result
10×10 Array{Int64,2}:
  1  11  21  31  41  51  61  71  81   91
  2  12  22  32  42  52  62  72  82   92
  3  13  23  33  43  53  63  73  83   93
  4  14  24  34  44  54  64  74  84   94
  5  15  25  35  45  55  65  75  85   95
  6  16  26  36  46  56  66  76  86   96
  7  17  27  37  47  57  67  77  87   97
  8  18  28  38  48  58  68  78  88   98
  9  19  29  39  49  59  69  79  89   99
 10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100
```

which is basically equivalent to the naive, explicit solution

```
julia> result = Matrix{Int64}(undef, m,n);

julia> for k in eachindex(i) result[k] = i[k] end

julia> result
10×10 Array{Int64,2}:
  1  11  21  31  41  51  61  71  81   91
  2  12  22  32  42  52  62  72  82   92
  3  13  23  33  43  53  63  73  83   93
  4  14  24  34  44  54  64  74  84   94
  5  15  25  35  45  55  65  75  85   95
  6  16  26  36  46  56  66  76  86   96
  7  17  27  37  47  57  67  77  87   97
  8  18  28  38  48  58  68  78  88   98
  9  19  29  39  49  59  69  79  89   99
 10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100
```

Comment: That was quite helpful, thanks! I guess when I want the sequence to be row-wise, I'd have to transpose the array in the end using `transpose()`